# How can I clone an openssl::ssl::SslStream?

Tags: rust, stream

`std::net::TcpStream` has the [`try_clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.try_clone) method to clone the underlying socket, but there's nothing similar for [`openssl::ssl::SslStream`](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.29/openssl/ssl/struct.SslStream.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to clone an `SslStream` as the SSL / TLS logic contains state. All the clones need to agree on and update that state.

In fact, it *used* to implement `Clone` and it was [deprecated](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/commit/e85b49d3755375b3e535cbd4b07d4fbf953948cb) and [removed](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/commit/58654bc49140d37f28837ba1982ed4aa9fc5c466) because it was a large footgun.

You will need to wrap it in an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` or equivalent and clone that. Another approach would be to restructure your code so that only one thing has ownership of the stream and you communicate via other techniques.

See also:

- [Do I need to move away from Tokio as I cannot split streams in TLS connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61088639/155423)
- [Separate TcpStream + SslStream into read and write components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40233482/155423)